# How to avoid redis queu lose if a redis task ends

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-ecs, elastic-cache

I have a service running always one task which loads a docker Redis image. This service runs in an ECS.

Now my question is: Given this configuration, if the Redis task ends, it will load a new Redis task. However, I understand the queu Redis has will be lost. Is there any way to keep the Redis queu so the next Redis task will take it? Do I have to use any other Amazon system? (Elasticache?)

Comment: The easiest way would be elasticache or memorydb, but you can configure persistence on ECS with some effort. Note that elasticache and standard persistent setups are not fully durable and still have some small risk of dataloss. AWS claims this is not the case with memorydb and is fully durable.

Comment: Mainly I use Redis for Celery broker and I was thinking using Spot instances. In any case, even without spot a failure can happen. Is memorydb something different to Redis?

Comment: Memorydb is a newer redis service from AWS

Comment: If you're just looking for a durable Queue backend for Celery on AWS, you might be better off looking at SQS instead of Redis. https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/sqs.html It would almost certainly be cheaper.

Comment: I saw it but my api endpoints using celery can have an image up to 2MB for post data, and in SQS it says it can store up to 256kb, so I understood i couldn't use that. But actually I saw now that you can if you use https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-extended-client-lib I will have a check...